# what is the nearest sine and cosine function to form half hexagon function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

i need a function with consist of sin or cosine function to form a half hexagon wave. Could anyone suggest any? The one that I have is $$ 4\sin (0.25x) + \sin (0.75x) $$

which is quite close to what I want, but if possible I want a smooth top and bottom (to almost straight line).

Could anyone suggest a function please and thank you.

Comment: Do you know about [Fourier coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) and how to calculate them?

Comment: @andrewD.Hwang not really to be honest... didn't plan to go tha far. I need a simple one just as a trajectory for my game, perhaps somebody already have them kept

Comment: If you mean that the part of the graph that's above the $x$-axis must be shaped approximately like half a hexagon, then definitely Fourier series can do it. $\qquad$

Comment: @michaelHardy. yes that's what I want but I do not know Fourier series